# Can you create a copy of a concrete object from an abstract reference

Tags: c++

I have a set of classes: Value, ReportItem, ReportMessage.  The Value class is abstract with a number of different concrete implementations (e.g. IntValue, FloatValue, DoubleValue, etc.)  The concrete classes are added to the ReportItem when it is created by passing a reference to the value:

```
ReportItem(Value& value);
```

ReportItems are then added a ReportMessage using an "addItem" method, which takes a copy of the report item and squirrels it away:

```
class ReportMessage {
    ...
    void addItem(ReportItem item);
}
```

So a code snippet might look like this:

```
IntValue value(1);
ReportItem item(value);

ReportMessage message;
message.addItem(item);
```

I don't have a problem with creating a copy of the ReportItem but I have a problem with the Value because it is an abstract class.  When the ReportItem is created, it takes a reference to the Value object and holds onto that reference until the ReportItem is deleted. This is problem because if the Value object is deleted before the ReportItem is finished with it, the earth will fall off its axis and spiral into the sun.

Is there a good way to deal with this problem? What I would like is a way to take a reference to a Value object (Value&) and somehow create a copy of the concrete object, which would then be held onto by the report item.  Is that possible, or is there a better approach.

Thanks.

NOTE: I'm not using C++11.

Comment: Just make the `ReportItem` own the value and handle it via a base pointer.

Comment: Having it as a pointer you can handle copying with the [clone pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

As a simplified example, here's how you could make the `ReportItem` class own the value. You need to work hard on copy and assignment semantics ("virtual copy constructor" etc), but I leave that to you to work out (i.e. search for existing answer on this site):

```
class ReportItem
{
    Value * vptr;    // vptr is the first thing in the class
public:
    ReportItem(int n) : vptr(new IntValue(n)) { }
    ReportItem(float x) : vptr(new FloatValue(x)) { }
    ~ReportItem() { delete vptr; }

    // write difficult copy and assignment logic!
};
```

Not having C++11 makes this quite a bit more cumbersome than it needs to be, since you don't have sensible move semantics and probably need to make lots of unnecessary copies.

(In C++11, you'd simply have a `std::unique_ptr<Value>` member, no explicit destructor, and you could say `message.addItem(ReportItem(1.5));`.)

Comment: That won't work for me because I have to deal with Value derived classes, not primitive types. I think the clone pattern is likely what I'll have to use.

Comment: The class can be modified to take a template constructor instead.

Comment: If you don't have C++.11, you can use Boost's `shared_ptr<>` instead. It will give proper destructor, copy, and assignment semantics, but it does have the added cost of reference count manipulations.